# "Not in" constraint using JPA criteria

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am trying to write a `NOT IN` constraint using `JPA Criteria`.
I've tried something like this:

```
builder.not(builder.in(root.get(property1)));
```

though I know it will not work. In the above syntax, how can I add the collection / list against which `property1` that will be checked?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`builder.not(root.get({field_name}).in(seqs))`
seqs is collection.

Comment: Also possible: `root.get({field_name}).in(seqs).not()`